# Custom Sort of ObjectListView

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

can somebody help me? I am trying to do custom sort of items in objectlistview. I have found a method using BeforeSorting event. Items are sorted, but objectlistview are showing "old data".
The source of items for objectlistview is _shows.

```
private void objectListView1_BeforeSorting(object sender, BeforeSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        _shows.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name != "News").ThenBy(s => s.Name);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the returned sorted collection, it should be:

```
_shows = 
_shows.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name != "News").ThenBy(s => s.Name);
```

This will result in `IOrderedCollection`, in case `_shows` is a `List`, then to `ToList()` post `ThenBy`

Post this I assume that you rebind the Datagridview with the data source `_shows` and thus the correct values will be reflected

Comment: It was a stupid mistake, but still not working. I don't know how to "refresh" objectlistview or its data source.

Comment: I am assuming that Data Source is the _shows, which is getting sorted above. Now you just need to re-bind the same to object list view in another event, similar to the way you have initially bound. That event can be a simple button click

Comment: I didn't know, that I need to use different event. Now it's working. Thank you.